# Inside an array, how to check forript?

Tags: object, reactjs

So I will be constantly retrieving an object with the following format:

```
student: {
    "student_id": "12345",

                "location": "below",
            },
        ]
    },
]
```

Thank you and will accept answer and upvote!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should do the trick:

```
var students = [];

function addStudent(student) {
  // Check if we already know about this student.
  var existingRecord = students.find(function (s) {
    return s.student_id === student.student_id;
  });

  var classInfo = {
    class_number: student.class_number,
    location: student.location
  };

  if (!existingRecord) {
    // This is the first record for this student so we construct
    // the complete record and add it.
    students.push({
      student_id: student.student_id,
      classes: [classInfo]
    });

    return;
  }

  // Add to the existing student's classes.
  existingRecord.classes.push(classInfo);
}
```

You would then invoke it as follows:

```
addStudent({
    "student_id": "67890",
    "class_number": "abcd",
    "location": "below",
});
```

Runnable JSBin example available [here](http://jsbin.com/cusocudaze/edit?js,console).

More available on `Array.prototype.find` [at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find).

Comment: Just gave it an attempt, and with one `student` object, it was able to add successfully, but when I tried to add two `student` objects with same `student_id`, the first `classInfo` object got added properly, and the second `classInfo` object got added in the correct place but with the `student_id` as well inside it. Where could be causing the problem? I tried log testing but can't seem to locate it. Thanks again jabclab

Comment: Disregard the previous comment. Was a mistake on my end. Thank you so much! Accepted the answer and upvoted. But for learning purposes, what is `students.find(function (s))` doing?

Comment: @JoKo glad it helped :-) You can read more about `Array.prototype.find` here https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find.

Answer (score 1):

This problem can be solved using indexing by `student_id`. For example:

```
var sourceArray = [{...}, {...}, ...];

var result = {};

sourceArray.forEach(function(student){

    var classInfo = {
        class_number: student.class_number,
        location    : student.location
    };

    if(result[student.student_id]){

        result[student.student_id].classes.push(classInfo);

    } else {

        result[student.student_id] = {
            student_id  : student.student_id,
            classes     : [classInfo]
        }

    }
});


// Strip keys: convert to plain array

var resultArray = [];

for (key in result) {
    resultArray.push(result[key]);
}
```

You can use also `result` format that contains objects, indexed by `student_id` or plain array `resultArray`.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, previous answer works, however my code more fast, because it don't use any methods like find(). This is especially important for large arrays.